# NSServerNotificationCenter and a Linux server

Tags: cocoa, push-notification

In one of my Mac apps, I have the need of having PUSH notifications. Instead of using some custom solution, I thought I might as well give `NSServerNotificationCenter` a try. Apple's docs mention a `notificationconf` command, which my Ubuntu server does not have. The docs also mention that `NSServerNotificationCenter` uses XMPP.

My question is basically this - I have ejabberd running on my server, could I just connect to that from my code? How would I post a notification to a user using this? I also need a way to let my `NSServerNotificationCenter` know my user's credentials - I presume I would do this using an `NSTask` and run `notificationconf setpass hostname username`.

Does anyone know how I should go about setting this up? I also need to find a way to create a new ejabberd user when a user is registered through PHP, but that should be no problem.

Then again, if this isn't possible too easily, is there another way of doing push notifications on the Mac with an Ubuntu server running the server part?

Thanks for any responses, this topic is seriously confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with this class suggests that it is really only meant to communicate with an OS X Server (i.e. Mac running the server package/version of the OS) and only meant to do push notifications for Mail and iCal. Very limited!

But XMPP is definitely the way to do push notifications here! I suggest you check out the [XMPPframework project](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/GettingStarted_MacOSX) from [the Deusty guys](http://deusty.blogspot.com/). It's a Cocoa implementation of XMPP and should work nicely with ejabberd (though I use [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)).

There are also a handful of PHP-XMPP frameworks. Check out [xmpphp on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/).

Lot's more [information for other frameworks and languages here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Comment: Thanks.. I had already set up an XMPP server for chatting on my server in the first place, so I could probably easily do PUSH notifications. It's a shame that the class Apple has there is so darn limited!